# Jackson Data Binding for LocalDate[] using annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, jsr310

I am converting a JSON file into Java object using Jackson with Java 8 Module. But while converting JSON array to LocalDate[] application is throwing an exception.

**How to convert below JSON array to LocalDate[] using annotations?**

**JSON**

```
{
    "skip": [
        "01/01/2019",
        "26/01/2019"
    ]
}
```

**Code**

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate[] skip;
```

**Exception**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING) within Array, expected VALUE_NUMBER_INT
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 25, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.saalamsaifi.springwfrlroster.model.Team["skip"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateDeserializer.java:38)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
```

Comment: Remove the JsonSerialize and JsonDeserialize annotations.

Comment: Why not omitting the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations altogether,
and instead registering the [`JavaTimeModule`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-datatype-jsr310/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) to your `ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `skip` is of type **array**, `LocalDateSerializer`, `LocalDateDeserializer` and `JsonFormat` do not work out of the box - they are implemented to expect direct value tokens and not arrays.

You can implement your own serializer/deserializers. A naive deserializer I implemented to deserialize your example is the following:

```
public class CustomLocalDateArrayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate[]> {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

  @Override
  public LocalDate[] deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonToken currentToken = p.getCurrentToken();
    if (currentToken != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
      throw new JsonMappingException(p, "Not an array!");
    }

    currentToken = p.nextToken();

    while (currentToken != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
      if (currentToken != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
        throw new JsonMappingException(p, "Not a string element!");
      }

      LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(p.getValueAsString(), formatter);
      list.add(localDate);

      currentToken = p.nextToken();
    }

    return list.toArray(new LocalDate[0]);
  }
}
```

And I changed the field annotation to be `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateArrayDeserializer.class)`.

You can work on it to iterate & improve over it, make it read&respect `@JsonFormat` annotation and so on, if you think it is worth the effort.

Comment: There is no need to do all that. Just removing the annotations is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you @Utku Özdemir your solution worked for me. But I wanted to do it by some annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect looking at your code and your json model it is trying to convert to an array using a deserializer that is defined for one object. It simple terms you are trying to convert a single item to an array which it cant parse. You could Try a list of LocalDate instead. Something Like:

```
List<LocalDate> skip;
```

You might even need to create your own Deserializer based on the date serializer.

Answer (score -1):

Just first glance: are actually json objects in your json array or just Strings as you showed? This should be something like this:
{
    "skip": [
        "key1":"01/01/2019",
        "key2":"26/01/2019"
    ]
}